# Jest, Received promise resolved instead of rejected

Tags: async-await, jestjs

I have this code:

```
await expect(response)
  .rejects.toThrow(new Error('Invalid transaction identifier'));
```

When I run the test with that `await` I get that error message:

```
"Received promise resolved instead of rejected"
```

If I remove the `await` before the `expect` the test works, but my linter is warning me this:

[image]

I don't get why

Comment: You should show the actual code not a screen shot. However, your screen shot indicates you do not have the await.

Comment: that's what I said, without the await, the IDE shows that war that I need the await, but the test only works without the await, so I don't get it. I will update the question with more code

Comment: This means that `response` isn't a rejected promise, simple as that. It's a mistake to remove `await` because this results in unhandled error occurring outside the test. The test itself may pass but if test suite runs long enough, it will appear later.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the test in an async/await.

```
it('should wait for response', async done => {
    await serviceCall().then( ... => {
        expect(response).rejects.toThrow( ... );
    });
   done();
});
```

where the ... are replaced with the full syntax.  The `async done => {` is the big part in your test, and then the final line of `done()` to complete the async waiting.